# multiple attendance entry in rails database with nested forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

I am currently using Ruby v 2.0.0p195 and rails v 3.2.13

I am very new to rails and to ruby and have dived in there to learn how to do all this by getting into an interesting project.

I want to create an entry form for a school attendance record that will list the student names and provide the opportunity to update their records simultaneously for a given date. i.e one big button on the form that updates a selected date for all the students at once while giving the opportunity to mark particular students as absent.

I am already using the existing student controller methods to create individual records for the students and that works fine. I can even create an individual attendance register for each student and that works as well, but when I attempt to put the entire group in one list I am not able to get it to work and I am lost as to how to proceed.

Do I create a new method in the student controller using a nested form approach or do I use the attendance controller methods that aren't being used for anything to create and edit these records. If I use the attendance controller how do I list the students and link these records from within the attendance controller?

I have 2 tables:

student and attendance

student.rb

```
has_many :attendances, :dependent => :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :attendances, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

attendance.rb

```
attr_accessible :present, :attdate, :absent, :partial, :notified, :notes, :student_id

belongs_to :student, :class_name => 'Student'
```

The routes.rb looks like this:

```
root to: 'home_page#home'
get 'attendance/:id', to: 'students#attentry'
get 'attendance', to: 'students#attentry'

resources :attendances

resources :students do
   member do
     get 'attentry'
   end
end

resources :students do
resources :attendances
end

resources :students

get 'students/attentry'
```

I think some of my routes are getting confused as I have had to add bits to get individual things working.

the controller method I am currently using for my student attendance is this:

```
def attentry
    @student = Student.find(params[:id])
    @attendance = @student.attendances.build

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render action: "attentry" }
  format.json { render json: @student }
 end
end
```

and the view is this:

```
<%= form_for (@student) do |f| %>  
<%= f.text_field :name -%>
    <div class="span9">
        <table class = "table table-striped">
      <tr>
    <td>Date</td>
    <td>Present</td>
    <td>Absent</td>
    <td>  Part Day</td>
    <td>Notified</td>
    <td>Notes</td>
      </tr>
        <%= f.fields_for :attendances do |fc| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= fc.text_field :attdate %></td>
        <td><%= fc.check_box :present %></td>
        <td><%= fc.check_box :absent %></td>
        <td><%= fc.text_field :partial %></td>
        <td><%= fc.check_box :notified %></td>
        <td><%= fc.text_area :notes, :rows => 3 %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      </div>
     </table>

    <br />


  <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

Anyway, what I get is a table that shows all the attendance details for one student and I am attempting to get all the students on one table so I can update them all in one go with a button and check boxes.

Is this more a Javascript thing or can I do this while remaining in Ruby/Rails land?

I have been going through a lot of railscasts and stack overflow posts and have been gradually putting it together and patching things together, but this part has had me stumped for weeks. I am beginning to wonder if the version of Ruby and Rails is what is giving me the headaches as a lot of what I have found as potential answers just don't seem to work properly even when they are created verbatim from the rails casts etc......thanks in advance for any ideas, suggestions, places to look.

Comment: After a lot of railscasts and stack overflow and all sorts of googling I have made some ground on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that assisted me in achieving the multiple update form was this in the attendance controller and this is what helped me through the problem:

```
def multiplenew
   if params["student_ids"].nil? 
      @attendance = Attendance.create(params[:attendance])

   else
     params["student_ids"].each do |id|
     @student = Student.find(id.to_i)
     @attendance = @student.attendances.create(params[:attendance])
     end
   end

   redirect_to attendances_url
end
```

Basically it gathers the id info from the checkboxes that are located next to each student and creates a daily attendance record for each one that is ticked. There are a number of default values for the fields so it works nice and smoothly. I also set up the validations so that a date could not be repeated for any particular student which was made in the model.

It's using a little of the multiple edit concept from the railscasts by the fantastic Ryan Bates, a massive amount of time on Stack Overflow, a lot of reading of the api and the rails guides and a little voodoo, but this code section helped me to create multiple attendance records from one submit button press and a bunch of checkboxes. It also allows for creating blank days in case of days with no attendance required. Even got some javascript in there as well. One happy camper! Now onto getting this to change into a multiple edit page.......

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do the same thing so I would love to see how you got everything to fit together.